# Whats the alternative way to serialize inherited types in WCF

Tags: web-services, wcf

I want to use inherited types in WCF ,but i dont want to add KnownType attribute of all types in the base class, because the base is in another assembly ,also to avoid dependencies. 
So, what are the other way to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

I think there are at least two ways to do this.

1. You can create your own classes (DTO) and map data from other assembly to your classes. For mapping you can use AutoMapper. It has following advantages:

   - Your communication layer is separeted from your logic (I'm assuming that this other assembly contains logic)
   - You will decide how your API looks like and your protocol will not change without your knowledge (I'm assuming here that this other assembly is a library or someone else is responsible for it).
2. You can add `ServiceKnownType` to your ServiceContract interface more or less like below (I did not test the code):

   ```
   [DataContract]
   public class BaseClass {}

   [DataContract]
   public class DerivedClass : BaseClass  {}

   [ServiceKnownType(typeof(BaseClass))]
   [ServiceKnownType(typeof(DerivedClass))]
   [ServiceContract()]
   public interface IYourContract
   {
       [OperationContract]
       BaseClass[] GetClasses();
   }
   ```

   For more information check out documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.serviceknowntypeattribute.aspx). There is really good example.

**Which is beter?**

It depends on what you need. If your are developing prototype or you need to do something fast go for option 2. If you need more reliable solution, that will stay with you longer choose option 1.

Comment: Thank for your anwser, but thats mean i have to receate all my classes which are hundreds, repeating and need so much work.
Ans the second way, my service much know about my classes which is strong coupling, and i dont want that.My service must only knows about the base class.

Comment: But your service have to know about all classes for example to generate WSDL in case of `BasicHttpBinding`.  You cannot separate WCF from transported objects. You should not think about WCF like it is an interface. WCF allows you to create api / protocol and it has to be well defined. I would say that  strong coupling is desired here.

Comment: Thats a good point, but my service also inherits from other service, i dont know if that gonna work or give me other issues .This is going to be my last solution if i dont find a better one.

Answer (score 1):

There are more ways of specifying the known types. One of them is to put them in your configuration file. That way your service doesn't know about them at compile time. But in order to serialize them, it has to know about them at runtime.

Comment: Thats sounds reasonable,but how to do that, can you provide me a tutorial or some references.

Comment: No, not really, I would have to google it, but you can do that yourself.

Comment: It didn't occur to me until now, but another option is to use you DI container if you have one. You would register all the derived types for the base class and then you request all of them. You can then tell WCF programmatically what the known types are. Again, I don't know the API, but this is the third way to add known types that I'm aware of.